# mysql_query update value 2 by 2

Tags: php, mysql

when i run the below mysql query in mysql front end the value increase by one:

Query: `update tableName set ColA=ColA+1`

```
previous value: 12
value after running query(1st time): 13
value after running query(2nd time): 14
```

But when i run the same query through my php script then it's always update 2 by 2.

```
<?php
mysql_query("update tableName  set ColA=ColA+1",$conn); 
?>

previous value: 12
value after running query(1st time): 14
value after running query(2nd Time): 16
value after running query(3rd Time): 18
```

why it's happening?

```
PHP Version 5.4.24
Mysql Version: 5.5.14
IIS version: 7
```

Comment: Did you check if the query isn't somewhere else in your code as well? So the query is running twice..

Comment: what is type of you column?

Comment: It's hard to check the issue with the details provided. You may need to share more. The possible cause is the query is run twice. Are you using OOPs?

Comment: i checked everywhere. it's running only once. column type varchar. i have checked through bigint. but both case it's same.

Comment: Is that field an autoincriment field??

Comment: put some `echo` statement with `mysql_query` and check weather it is printed once or twice.

Comment: @jack.. does it really matters?

Comment: it's not an auto incremental field.

Comment: Print your query in the code then copy it into mysql. Check wether it is showing or not.mysql_query("update tableName  set ColA=ColA+1",$conn);  echo("update tableName  set ColA=ColA+1");

Comment: yes i have checked & it's showing properly.

Comment: Use like this mysql_query("update tableName  set `ColA`=ColA+1",$conn);  This is not MySQL issue but PHP. Single and Double Quotes are different

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
mysql_query("update tableName  set `ColA`=ColA+1",$conn);
```

Or

```
mysql_query("update tableName  set `ColA`=`ColA`+1",$conn);
```

This is not MySQL issue but PHP. Single and Double Quotes are different...

Comment: No progress. it's same as previous.

Comment: Try with a myql variable

Comment: :( Post here if there is any progress